# mfrc522 Arduino library -> RFID ERROR: PCD_Authenticate() failed: Timeout in communication

Tags: arduino, rfid, nfc, mfrc522

I'm trying to do a project using RFID tags to store information to be retrieved later with another device. Kind of a storage memory.

I've bougth several tags which I can write and read with several mobile phone APPs such as NFC Tools.

With an Arduino circuit using the MFRC522 library default examples I can read a credit card like RFID tag. However, when I try the tags I need for the project (Ultralight c sticker tags) I get an PCD_Authenticate() error.

I've read the possible keys that usually balcnk RFID tags use such as 0xFF ... but the tags I need seem not to have this key.

I've managed to get a dump of what I guess is the full tag memory shown below:

```
**Card Detected:**
DUMP  ----------------------------------------------------------
Page    0      1      2      3
  0     04     49     E3     26
  1     7A     FC     4E     80
  2     48     48     00     00
  3     E1     10     12     00
  4     01     03     A0     0C
  5     34     03     03     D0
  6     00     00     FE     00
  7     65     6E     48     6F
  8     6C     69     51     01
  9     30     54     02     65
 10     6E     49     64     65
 11     6E     74     69     66
 12     69     65     72     3A
 13     0A     30     34     20
 14     3A     20     34     39
 15     20     3A     20     45
 END DUMP  -------------------------------------------------------
Authentication failed: Timeout in communication.
Reading failed: Timeout in communication.
```

The card UID are the first 8 bytes: 04 49 E3 26 7A FC 4E 80 Which the Arduino library and the mobile APP can read successfully and show as card UID.

But I don't know why the mobile APPs can read and write the sticker card, but with the arduino library example code I get the Authentication error. And the error only occurs with the ultralight c sticker cards, with the classic Mifare cards do not seem to have this issue.

Can you please let me know why I'm having this Authentication error and how to solve it?

Lots of thanks in advance.

Comment: the cheaper mfrc522 boards have crappy antennas and have problems with reading DesFire cards and probably writing. Wind yourself a better antenna.

Comment: But I'm able to read all the data in the dump. Also I'm able to read other data on other cards. It seems more either a software issue or really needing the proper Key to authenticate successfully.

Comment: The crypto operations require more power and need a better antenna.

Comment: ok, do you know a good and cheap module for Arduino I can use?  OR what should I look for in the specs?

Comment: That’s a shopping question which is off topic here. You can fix your problem with a bit of Googling and a few turns of wire. Your antenna needs to be more credit card sized.

Comment: The one that I use is the Welleman VMA405 which the antena is aproximatelly a square 4 by 4 centimeters. Bigger than that?

Comment: I’d suggest you do some Googling as you’re not the first to encounter this problem.

Comment: Well it's been 4 days googling and trying several codes. The solution I found on google did not work for me as I tried their codes. That's why I posted this question here.

Comment: Code wont fix hardware problems. There’s plenty of info on how to make a rfid antenna for 13.58MHz.